# How do I get the petroleum truck out of the way?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I have a distinct MacGayver feeling about this section of Chapter 3. Train's stopped by a petrol truck hanging in the air. I've got some sort of wrench from the train and some sellotape, plus a bunch of people who doesn't seem to be offering much in ways of hints.

I *think* I've explored all action dots in the scenario and now I'm coming up empty. There's an empty generator conveniently placed right to the petrol tanks, but once you inspect it once you can't interact with it any further. You can inspect the hitch of the truck, but none of the tools I have will do anything to it. That's about it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a train station a little distances in the direction of travel. You can see it by standing by the bottom of ladders. You can walk there.

I suppose that's where the story continues.

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to go to the station first.